# "who " vs. "whom"

Tags: grammar

Original Sentence：
Yesterday I met the man **who** you said was the mayor of the city.

Q：
is it correct,if I rewrite the sentence as follows：

Sentence：
Yesterday I met the man **that** you said **him** was the mayor of the city.
=Yesterday I met the man **whom** you said was the mayor of the city.

Comment: *Yesterday I met the man **that** you said **him**...* sounds too strange to me

Answer (score 1):

*Him was*? No, that's not grammatical.

"Yesterday I met the man that you said **he** was the mayor of the city." is not normal English, but it is understandable, and I think grammatical.

Comment: clear, thank you for your help ^^